# What Not to Delete

Tags: kernel, files, filesystem, directory, system-info

I've been messing around on VM's, trying to figure out the best way to secure/ clean Ubuntu, and twice- in all my brilliance- I managed to delete a key component in starting Ubuntu (eg. init) because of false positives on programs like Clamav and Rkhunter. My question is, what types of files should I not delete/watch out for when cleaning my system?

UPDATE: More specifically, what files are crucial to running/starting the system?

Comment: "Cleaning" the system? How did it get dirty?

Comment: By clean I mean get rid of excess files, malware, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete any files in your **HOME** folder under :

- Desktop
- Documents
- Downloads
- Music
- Videos
- Pictures
- Public

Any hidden folders are out of the question in your *zombie apocalypse*.

Besides this folders, everything is used by your Operative system. And the other source of unnecessary data is old package files which can be cleaned automatically with :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Only problem is I'm only deleting files not in those directories to try to remove malware/viruses/unneeded programs

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove removes unnecessary (old version) deb packages. Do you think you have malware or you are trying to get your round-about it for regular checks ?

Comment: It's possible there is malware (most likely Trojans), and I also want to know because I often get false-positives from Clamav/rkhunter and I want to make sure I'm not deleting important files

Comment: PUA's are not likely to be malware in my experience but I haven't done much scans since I don't share files regularly. I got PUS on a compiler because it uses some kind of compression and the binary cannot be transparently read.